# Gravity Bow on magic bow

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Can the gravity bow spell be mixed with magic bow that has +1 fire on it? Or can you not have both magic effects on it together?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Yes, You Get [Gravity Bow](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/spells/gravityBow.html)'s Extra Damage When Using a Magic Bow

If the character is wielding a magic bow when he casts *gravity bow*, he'll do more damage from the virtually bigger arrows *and* more damage from the enhancement bonuses and weapon special abilities of his bow.

The increased damage from the spell is an effect of, essentially, bigger arrows: "Any arrow fired from a bow or crossbow you are carrying when the spell is cast deals damage as if one size larger than it actually is." This extra damage isn't an enhancement bonus--or any other kind of bonus, for that matter--so [stacking bonuses](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/gettingStarted.html#_stacking) isn't an issue.

Answer (score 1):

They add just fine. These are independent magical effects.

When combining magical effects, you mostly need to worry about stacking (see [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Stacking)), but that does not come into play here.